# Variable in title for ggplot.Predict

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ggplot.Predict (from the `rms` package) in a function to produce graphs automatically:

```
library(rms)

ddist <- datadist(iris); options(datadist="ddist")

mod <- ols(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data=iris)

p.plot <- function(pred, ttl) {
          ggplot(pred, 
          addlayer=labs(title=ttl))
}

plot.title <- "Sepal length"

p.plot(Predict(mod), plot.title)
```

This results in an "Error in labs(title = ttl) : object 'ttl' not found" The following however works without problems.

```
ggplot(Predict(mod), addlayer=labs(title=plot.title))
```

Comment: What package does `ggplot.Predict()` come from? That's a very unusual way to overload the `ggplot` function.

Comment: The `rms` package.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Right now it's hard to test your code since we don't know exactly what you are passing to this function.

Comment: But rather than using `addlayer=`, try just adding `+labs(title=ttl)` after the `ggplot()` call.

Comment: Thank you very much - this solves the problem. The error seems to result from the way ggplot.Predict passes on variables to addlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick) in the comments:

Rather than using `addlayer=`, try just adding `+ labs(title=ttl)` after the `ggplot()` call:

```
p.plot <- function(pred, ttl) {
          ggplot(pred) +
              labs(title=ttl)
}
```